# WPF Datagrid DataTemplate ComboBo Not Capturing Change in Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've gotten a lot of help from SO on this so far, but I've come to a pace where I've gotten stuck.  I can get this to work for a singular combobox, but it isn't jiving when I do this in a DataGridTemplate.  I would expect the FXCItem property to get whatever value is selected from the combobox, but it alway returns null.  Furthermore, the 'SET' method in my ConfigItems property isn't being thrown at all.  What am I missing here?  Thank you in advance!

ViewModel & Model (this is populated on a button 'click' event):

```
   class ConfigViewModel : ViewModelEntity
{

    public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    public List<String> FileTypes { get; set; }
    public List<String> Delimiters { get; set; }
    public List<string> FXCFields { get; set; }

    protected ObservableCollection<ConfigItem> _ConfigItems = new ObservableCollection<ConfigItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<ConfigItem> ConfigItems
    {
        get { return _ConfigItems; }
        set
        {
            if (_ConfigItems != value)
            {
                _ConfigItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ConfigItems");
            }

        }
    }}

class ConfigItem
{
    public string InputField { get; set; }
    public string FXCField { get; set; }

    public ConfigItem(string InputFieldName)
    {
        this.InputField = InputFieldName;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgConfig" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40.66,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300.486" Width="323" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InputField}" Header="Input Fields"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FXC Fields">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.FXCFields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FXCItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.FXCFields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FXCItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Where you have defined FXCItem ?

Comment: @RAJ, You nailed it!  Thanks so much!  I had the binding property misnamed!  I've been looking at this for too long and I couldn't see the forest from the trees!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("FXCFields");
```

Comment: I tried that just now with no luck.  The ConfigItems's Set method isn't being called at all.  I expanded the FXCFields property to implement the NotifyProperyhChanged on Set as well with no luck.